# Разбить колонку на 6 столбцов в plsql

Tags: plsql

Необходимо разбить колонку на 6 столбцов. Точки с запятыми с ; - ;;;;;;; указывают границы. В 5 столбце нужно учитывать следующее правило - между ;;;; и ;;;;; где DЦЦБ  необходимо брать B50787.

|  |
| --- |
| Програм C;Деятели;;1999;;;94(574);;;;^A0^B50780^C20020129^DЦ-ка2^E425^U2000/058^A0^B50780^C20020129^DЦ-ка4^E428^U2000/058^B50780^C20020129^DЦ-ка12^E553^U2000/058^A0^B50780^C20020129^DЦ-ка7^U2000/058^A0^B50780^C20020129^DЦ-ка8^U2000/058^A0^B50787^C20020129^DЦЦБ^U2000/058;;;;;325;;;;;;; |
| :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------: |
| Дом;Рукопись;;2001;;;82-3;;;;^A0^B62661^C20020204^DЦЦБ^U2001/008;;;;;194;;;;;;; |
| :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------: |
| ;Тома;;2001;;;159.9;;;;^A0^B54649^C20020129^DЦЦБ^U2001/087;;;;;804;;;;;;; |

Выходная таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710589/is-there-a-function-to-split-a-string-in-oracle-pl-sql